# A timeout connection to AWS documentDb with ssl enabling

Tags: c#, timeout, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I'm creating new cluster of documentDb in AWS and trying to connect with my net.core application by MongoDriver to it. Cluster with Ssl enabled property.

According to [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836737/cannot-connect-to-aws-database-using-tls-with-server-ca-validation) I have tried couple ways for reaching my goal.

- Import chain of certificates to local computer storage, into Trusted Root Certification Authorities [rds-combined-ca-bundle.p7b](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.p7b);
- Read the [pem](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem) file and create certificate in code for C# or use it in mongoShell with `--sslCAFile` param.

```cs
var clientSetting = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl("mongodb://<myloging>:<mypassword>@<myclusterendpoint>/?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0");

var setting = new MongoClientSettings()
{
    Server = clientSetting.Server,
    UseSsl = clientSetting.UseSsl,
    Credential = clientSetting.Credential,

    GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy,
    ReadPreference = new ReadPreference(ReadPreferenceMode.Primary),
    VerifySslCertificate = true,
    SslSettings = new SslSettings
    {
        ClientCertificates = new List<X509Certificate2>()
        {
            new X509Certificate2("<path>\\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
        },
        EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default,
        CheckCertificateRevocation = true
    },
    ReplicaSetName = clientSetting.ReplicaSetName

};

setting.SslSettings.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback = (sender, host, certificates, certificate, issuers) => setting.SslSettings.ClientCertificates.ToList()[0];
setting.SslSettings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

setting.MaxConnectionIdleTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

client = new MongoClient(setting);
```

And do this:

```cs
var filter = new BsonDocument("name", "mycollection");
var collectionCursor = client.GetDatabase("mydatabase").ListCollections(new ListCollectionsOptions { Filter = filter });
if (!collectionCursor.Any())
{
    throw new Exception("Collection not found");
}
```

I expect that will get collection with name `mycollection` or `Collection not found` exception, but getting

```
A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/<myclusterendpoint>" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/<myclusterendpoint>", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown" }] }.
```

Same problem when try to connect via MongoShell. Maybe problem is in different zones. Example: cluster created in us-east-2 and I try to connect from Ukraine. :)

**UPD**: Assume that I should be in one VPC for connecting to DocumentDb cluster.

Comment: did you solve your problem? i am having the similar problem. i am connecting to docdb from outside the vpc but i got a security group with any inbound (testing of course) but still keep timing out. no luck either TLS on or off in docdb params group.

Comment: sorry, just realised one of the answers is your own. thanks. will try that.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was in designe of access to AWS DocumentDB. [More info about database access out of VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html).

Answer (score 2):

I see couple of things you may want to look at:

- `UseSsl = clientSetting.UseSsl,` - Set this to `true`
- `new X509Certificate2("<path>\\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")` - You may need to read the file contents first rather than give the path based on the API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But problem is security designe of AWS DocumentDB access. I have tried to use database from my local machine that does not exists in VPC.